# Rails: how to add user ownership of a picture album in the album/new form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently working on my first rails project, a site for users to make albums and upload pics. I have the registration, logging in, and friending installed into my app. I'm trying to make it so that in the album creation form, you can see a list of your friends and select who you want to share access to the album with (meaning whoever you select would also be part of `@album.users`. I'm planning on using a checkbox (I can't think of any better way) to make this selection. However, I am not sure how to link the `friendship` model with the album/new form. This is how my form looks like:

album/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @album]), :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="formholder">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.check_box :friends %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

an error occurs on line #6 (
        `<%= f.check_box :friends %>`

the error:

`undefined method 'friends' for #<Album:0x007fa3a4a8abc0>`

I can understand why, but I don't know how to fix it. I have the typical friendship join model to add friends, and I want to be able to see a list of all the friends and select them. I think a following step would be to add something like `@album.users << @user.friendships.find_by_name(params[:friends])` in the create action in the albums controller, but I don't know how I would loop through the form that only returns one param for friends?

Here are my files:

Albums controller create action:

```
    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
      # not so sure about the following line.
      @album.users << @user.friendships.find_by_name(params[:friends])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
          format.html { redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end 
    end
```

album model

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
  validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :album_users
  has_many :users, :through => :album_user
  has_many :photos

end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

validates_format_of :name, :with => /[A-Za-z]+/, :on => :create
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 5, :on => :create

has_many :album_users
has_many :albums, :through => :album_users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums

has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
```

end

album_user model (join table to make many-to-many relationship between album, which has many users, and users, which has many albums)

```
class AlbumUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :user
end
```

friendship model

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```

let me know if you need any more info!! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just as a side note, don't use tabs in your code. Tabs are treated differently in different editors, and you could get into trouble if you mix tabs with spaces.

Comment: ooo thanks! so always use double spaces instead of tabs? is there a way to make 2 spaces the default spacing instead of the tab in Sublime? cuz it's annoying having to go back and fix it everytime I press ente

Comment: Open preferences, and add `"tab_size": 2,
 "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true` to it. It's JSON, so you may need to add curly braces or additional commas. And use `Beautify Ruby` from package control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `users_ids` (yes, two "s") to the list of accessible attributes of `Album`, and then use a "select multiple" on the `:users_ids` field.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:users_ids, User.all, :id, :name, :multiple => true) %>
```